# Back button not working in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Hello friends i have created two page one is `index.html` and second is `about.html` . I just want to add back button on `about.html` using jQuery mobile . i have tried it but back button is not working in my code i dont know what is the problem

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="data-add-back-btn ">Back</div>
        <div><h1>Page title</h1>
        <a href="about.html" data-role="button">About us</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try creating your back button by using `data-rel="back"` as follows:

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

**Full HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <div>
            <h1>Page title</h1>
            <a href="about.html" data-role="button">About us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the section `"Back" button links` of the online doc for more information: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Yes that works, but your sample code above closes an "A" tag with a "DIV".  As shown, it looks broken on render.  The end tag after Back should be an "</a>".

Comment: @B-Money : Thanks for notifying the mistake mate. I've just corrected it.